# x86-64 Assembly Loop

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

This question was proposed to me by a friend and I have no idea how to solve it.

```
loop:
    leal (%rdi, %rdi, 4), %eax
    leal (%rsi, %rax, 2), %eax
    leal 0(, %rax, 4), %edx
    cmpl %edx, %esi
    jge .L1
    leal (%rdi, %rdi, 2), %edx
.L3:
    addl %edx, %eax
    cmpl $-2, %esi
    jl .L3
.L1:
    rep ret
```

And is supposed to map to this loop in C,

```
int loop(int a, int b){
    int x, y;
    y = ____;
    for (____; ____; ____){
        ____;
    }
    return ____;
}
```

My attempt at converting the assembly to C,

```
y = 5a;
y = b + 2y;
x = 4y;
if (x < b){
    x = 3a;
    do{
        y += x;
    } while (b <= -2);
}
return y;
```

I assumed %eax = y, since 'y' in the code to fill is the first variable being assigned.
'x' follows as %edx since it's another assignment, and so should be at least part of the "Initialisation" of the for loop.
However this doesn't seem to fix into the blanks provided, so I am really stuck.

Comment: Yes, `y` is `eax`.

Comment: `x > b` and `b <= -3` and your code [compiles to the correct assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/LbGZUh). Well, you can `for (int i = 1; x > b && (x = 3 * a, i); i = 0) {
        do y += x; while (b <= -3);
    }` with the loop.

Comment: Interesting, but why is "-3" mapped to "$-2" in the assembly?

Comment: @pman It's not. `<= -3` is the same as `< -2`.

Comment: Can the loop have more than one expression in it and can the third expression in the initializer of the `for` loop be nothing?

Comment: Compiling a `for()` loop to `if () do {} while` is totally normal, and what GCC actually does in practice, especially with optimization enabled.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got a really close, if not perfect solution:

```
/* rdi = a, rsi = b */
/* rax = y, rdx = x */

/*
loop:
    leal (%rdi, %rdi, 4), %eax
    leal (%rsi, %rax, 2), %eax
    leal 0(, %rax, 4), %edx
    cmpl %edx, %esi
    jge .L1
    leal (%rdi, %rdi, 2), %edx
.L3:
    addl %edx, %eax
    cmpl $-2, %esi
    jl .L3
.L1:
    rep ret
*/

int loop(int a, int b){
    int x, y;
    y = b + (a * 5) * 2;
    for (x = y * 4; x > b;){
        do y += (x = a * 3); while(b < -2);
        break;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Not sure if `break;` is an issue but I can't find a better way.

Comment: I see why you've added break, however shouldn't the compiler just omit it since it would know the code below is unreachable?

Comment: Also I believe the ```y = b + (a * 5) * 2;``` should be ```y = b +  2 * (y = a * 5);```, then I'd say it's right

Comment: @pman No, the assignment to `y` is unneeded because it's already being assigned. Same value, same code.

Comment: @pman The compiler generates a check for `x > b` inside the loop if `break;` is omitted.

Comment: Hmm, it's not possible to put it onto one line then, though this is the best solution in my opinion thank you